# How to write WHEN THEN statement in Eloquent, or filter the result before get()?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following query:

```
$results = Product::where("active", "=", true)->leftJoin(/** something **/)->leftJoin(/** something **/);
```

The above array is then process in the view file:

```
foreach($results->get() as $item)
{
  // do something
}
```

Now, this view is too generic and shared between almost 50 pages. I cannot change the view in any possible way. Now, I need a way to change the query result in the controller, I am unable to filter result since it is `get()` in the view. I need to know how to inject WHEN statement of MySQL into my Eloquent Query (above  query using `Product` model).

How should I do that? I need something like this:

```
$results = Product::select("is_special WHEN price > 500 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' ")->where("active", "=", true)->leftJoin(/** something **/)->leftJoin(/** something **/);
```

I you have any other way for filtering the result before `get()`, I welcome that!

Comment: Tried `selectRaw`? It's not ideal, but the whole situation here doesn't seem to be ideal anyway.

Comment: can you elaborate more, please?

Comment: Just replace `select` with `selectRaw`. This prevents Laravel from parsing your select clause. While potentially dangerous when involving user input, it seems to be okey on this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just pre-process some of the results before? Such as

```
$preSelected = Product::select(/** something **/)->where(/** x **/);
```

and in another Controller function

```
$preSelected = Product::select(/** something else **/)->where(/** y **/);
```

And then later it would be the same

```
$results = $preSelected->where("active", "=", true)
             ->leftJoin(/** something **/)->leftJoin(/** something **/);
```

Or another option would be to use DB::raw

```
$results = Product::select(DB::raw('is_special WHEN price > 500 THEN true ELSE false'))
             ->where("active", "=", true)->leftJoin(/** something **/)
             ->leftJoin(/** something **/);
```

though I try to avoid `DB::raw` whenever possible to increase security and reduce the possibility of e.g. SQL injection.